# OPA web UI - Monitor and Administer policies

Tags: open-policy-agent

We are about to implement OPA in our project to make decisions based on user provided policies and facts. Is there any opensource tool available which acts an UI to transform user provided inputs into policy (in REGO language) and dataset (in JSON)? Any advice on this is highly appreciated. Thank you!